# Multi-Massive Research -- any interest in this?

Tags: discussion

Will provide missing details soon.

Comment: I'm interested, with the major caveat on my end that I'm out of academia for now. How to give credit is one thing, and what platform to collaborate through is another, as SE's don't seem the best suited for a task like this. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Im definately interested

Comment: I would be interested. I am submitting my PhD thesis next week and have broad research interests. Looking forward to more details.

Answer (score 1):

One of the strongholds of nationalism is access to detailed statistical data. So a multi-massive research project will at the very least benefit from being able to undertake a cross-country empirical application at a novel scale, while also benefiting from local insights as regards interpretation.

So let's see the formalization of this proposal.

Comment: It seems that, tentatively, there are four of us willing to work on this? Also - I agree that whatever we focus on ought to leverage to novelty of the approach. This will work better if we can get more researchers on board. Four people is more like a paper co-authored by amicable strangers.

Comment: For the economics discipline, six will be massive